# Adding additional space to UILabel to insert image

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilabel

I have an issue with adding image in the end of the text of the UILabel. How can I detect the size of the text in the label, then add additional space and insert image into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i write a little code for this:

```
-(void) labelSizeGetter
{
    UILabel * mylabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

    float heigth=25.0;//max height value of label.

    NSString *yourString = @"My great text";

    mylabel.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12];

    [mylabel setText:yourString];

    CGSize s = [mylabel.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12] 
                        constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(MAXFLOAT,heigth)
                            lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    // s is a size for text of label. just add 10 pix to width to make it more beautiful.

    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGSize(s));

    mylabel.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, s.width+10, s.height);

    [self.view addSubview:mylabel];

    UIView * myimage=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(mylabel.frame.origin.x+mylabel.frame.size.width , mylabel.frame.origin.y, 30, 30)];//create your images frame according to frame of your label

    myimage.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arti.png"]];

    [self.view addSubview:myimage];

}
```

i hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Best Way is take one `UIView`.

And Add Both `UILabel` And `UIImageView` on This `UIView` (*give **Fram** as per your Requirement*).

And This `UIView` to your **MainView** of `UIViewController`.

Comment: I thought about that, but I can't use it in current situation. I need to have additional space without adding UIView.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to use a UIView. Why not check the length of the string in the label. then add some additional space for your image using frame. [UILabel.text length] returns the length.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create some container UIView if you need or just use superview
2. Put there `UILabel` and `UIImageView`
3. Calculate a size of the text using `[NSString sizeWithFont:]` or similar `sizeWith...` method
4. Calculate position of your `UIImageView` according to a size of the text

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet which gives you size adjustable for specific font and specific font size. Accordingly you can set frame for your label and then image view as well.

```
- (CGSize)getSizeFromText:(NSString*)text {

    CGSize constrainedSize;

    constrainedSize.width = give maximum allowable width limit;

    constrainedSize.height = MAXFLOAT;

    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize] constrainedToSize:constrainedSize lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return size;
}
```

Hope this would help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a category on `NSString` that returns the size of a string when rendered with a given font. There are several methods, the most complete on being `- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font minFontSize:(CGFloat)minFontSize actualFontSize:(CGFloat *)actualFontSize forWidth:(CGFloat)width lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode` (see [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont%3aminFontSize%3aactualFontSize%3aforWidth%3alineBreakMode%3a)).

With that information you might be able to achieve what you want to do.